# Performance monitoring

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure

I need to get the performance metrics like CPU usage in sql server using sql query and store it in a history table , where I will keep on adding the old records . And a current table to maintain the present data .How can I do that , as I am working on the azure sql db currently I can't make use of sql server job agent to schedule . Please provide me with an alternative script

Comment: Are you looking for overall CPU usage in your Azure SQL database or CPU usage per query?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices here:

I know this does not let you save it in a table, but you have access to 30 days of CPU usage at any point without you doing anything. This is via matrics.

[image]

To collect the data from the two System dynamic management views I mentioned below, you can set up a collection at a set interval (similar to SQL Agent job) by using one of the following solutions. If you search Microsoft documentation, each of these solutions is documented in detail.

- Powershell with windows (or any other scheduler)
- Azure automation
- Azure function app
- [Elastic Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-overview)

[sys.restore_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-resource-stats-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) returns CPU usage and storage data for an Azure SQL Database. The data is collected and aggregated within five-minute intervals. For each user database, there is one row for every five-minute reporting window in which there is a change in resource consumption. The data returned includes CPU usage, storage size change, and database SKU modification. Idle databases with no changes may not have rows for every five-minute interval. Historical data is retained for approximately 14 days.

```
SELECT
  start_time, 
  end_time, 
  avg_cpu_percent 
from sys.resource_stats;
```

[sys.dm_db_resource_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-resource-stats-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) returns CPU, I/O, and memory consumption for an Azure SQL Database database. One row exists every 15 seconds, even if there is no activity in the database. Historical data is maintained for approximately one hour.

```
SELECT 
  end_time,
  avg_cpu_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;
```

You can set up [Azure diagnostic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/metrics-diagnostic-telemetry-logging-streaming-export-configure?tabs=azure-portal) which will save your metrics and logs to one of the three destinations. I personally use the log analytics workspace. You can then query your CPU usage using the Kusto Query language. An example Query would be:

```
// Avg CPU usage 
// Avg CPU usage in the last hour by resource name. 
//consistently high averages could indicate a customer needs to move to a larger SKU
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SQL" // /DATABASES
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(60min)
| where MetricName in ('cpu_percent') 
| parse _ResourceId with * "/microsoft.sql/servers/" Resource  // subtract Resource name for _ResourceId
| summarize CPU_Maximum_last15mins = max(Maximum), CPU_Minimum_last15mins = min(Minimum), CPU_Average_last15mins = avg(Average) by Resource , MetricName
```